# Правильное употребление глагола "выпустить"

Tags: употребление-слов

Подскажите как правильно употребить глагол в предложении: "Выпустить 25.06.2013г. из состава учащихся, сдавших квалиф. экзамен".

Answer (score 1):

Ни в одном приказе не видела слова "выпустить". Есть приказ о выбытии: Считать выбывшими из ... в связи с окончанием обучения следующих учащихся:.........................25.06.2013

ИЛИ(если нужно указать сдачу экзамена):Считать выбывшими из ... в связи с окончанием обучения следующих выпускников, успешно сдавших  квалификационный  экзамен:.........................25.06.2013

Если это не приказ, а отметка в журнале, то пишут: окончил школу, протокол № ..., дата

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, какое предложение Вы хотите составить и для чего.

Допустим, речь идет о выпускниках учебного заведения, и Вы составляете текст приказа. Тогда должно быть что-то вроде "отчислить из учебного заведения в связи с окончанием".

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, надо полностью менять фразу.